# Codeblocks Custom Build Command Hangs

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, makefile, codeblocks, fuse

I have an issue where when I type the build command into the terminal, it works just fine, but when I use it in Codeblocks as a custom build command, Codeblocks will say that it's compiling, suck up 100% CPU, but not actually do anything. Here's my configuration:

- I have a FUSE drive (sftp) set up at /home/david/The\ Quest\ of\ the\ Ions/ on the client which links to an identical directory on the server.
- The build command that codeblocks runs is: `ssh david@website.com 'cd /home/david/The\ Quest\ of\ the\ Ions/ && $make -f $makefile $target'`
- When I run the same build command as listed above in a terminal (with the variables filled in), it will fully complete without any user input.
- Makefile:

  CC=g++
  CFLAGS=-c -Wall
  LDFLAGS=
  SOURCES=main.cpp src/room.cpp
  OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
  EXECUTABLE=The\ Quest\ of\ the\ Ions

  all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

  $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
      $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

  Debug: all

  Release: all

  .cpp.o:
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

I am stumped on this problem and don't know what could be causing it. Thank you for your assistance!